# Dual boot issues - same disk Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, windows

I've been researching for hours on how to fix my problem, and have just decided it is probably best for me to just restart the process using what's recommended to me. **I'm well aware that there are other posts that address parts of these issues, although I cannot find one that answers all my questions, particularly my issue of installing Ubuntu and Windows dual-boot on the same disk rather than separate ones**

Could anyone here please instruct me on how I should best dual boot both Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

I am installing the two OS's on a 1 TB M2 SSD where Windows is being allocated 768 GB while Ubuntu is being allocated 256 GB.

My questions are:

- In what order should I install these OS's?
- What file format should the disk/partition be?
- In the past I've had issues with EFI/UEFI trying to do this. Why is this important and what does this mean for my installation today?
- Are the any particular considerations I should have doing this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: OSes installed in the same or different drives is largely irrelevant, procedure is the same. Although you can now use different file *systems*, EXT4 is still preferred and the default, this is something you shouldn't be worried about because the installer does that automatically. UEFI mode is obviously preferred and has HUGE advantages, namely it makes the order of installation completely irrelevant. The only consideration that perhaps isn't included in the next link is that you must disable Fast Startup in Windows, optionally disable Secure Boot and Fast Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Some more links:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  Usually best to install Windows first, but with UEFI less critical.  You must be sure to boot both installers in UEFI boot mode. what brand/model system? What video card/chip? Some brands have a few unique settings. Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware to latest available?